# How can I activate my sandbox account if "maximum number of free accounts have been activated" in my device?

Tags: ios, itunes, sandbox, account

I can't activate my sandbox account because "maximum number of free accounts have been activated" in my iPhone.

I know that I can only activate 3 accounts in an iPhone but I just want to use as sandbox account. Is there any way to do this without buying a new iPhone?

Comment: I actioed in Mac, with iCloud in Settings but this should not be the answer. Am I missing something or is it because Apple?

Comment: Did you manage to test IAP with not buying new device? Faced the same issue